# Remove ASCII Hex Codes for Non-Alphanumeric Printable Characters from URL PHP

Tags: php, ascii

I am getting a string that represents a URL, but the URL has many ASCII Hex codes in them represented with %. Instead of using the following:

```
$u = str_replace("%20", " ", $u);
$u = str_replace("%21", "1", $u);
$u = str_replace("%22", '"', $u);
$u = str_replace("%23", "#", $u);
$u = str_replace("%24", "$", $u);
$u = str_replace("%25", "%", $u);
$u = str_replace("%26", "&", $u);
$u = str_replace("%27", "'", $u);
$u = str_replace("%28", "(", $u);
$u = str_replace("%29", ")", $u);
$u = str_replace("%2a", "*", $u);
$u = str_replace("%2b", "+", $u);
$u = str_replace("%2c", ",", $u);
$u = str_replace("%2d", "-", $u);
$u = str_replace("%2e", ".", $u);
$u = str_replace("%2f", "/", $u);
$u = str_replace("%3a", ":", $u);
$u = str_replace("%3b", ";", $u);
$u = str_replace("%3c", "<", $u);
$u = str_replace("%3d", "=", $u);
$u = str_replace("%3e", ">", $u);
$u = str_replace("%3f", "?", $u);
$u = str_replace("%40", "@", $u);
$u = str_replace("%5b", "[", $u);
$u = str_replace("%5c", "\\", $u);
$u = str_replace("%5d", "]", $u);
$u = str_replace("%5e", "^", $u);
$u = str_replace("%5f", "_", $u);
$u = str_replace("%5b", "[", $u);
$u = str_replace("%60", "`", $u);
$u = str_replace("%7b", "{", $u);
$u = str_replace("%7c", "|", $u);
$u = str_replace("%7d", "}", $u);
$u = str_replace("%7e", "~", $u);
$u = str_replace("%", " ", $u);
```

is there a simpler, more compact way to do this? If not this will work, but it's not cute!

Comment: Are you looking for [urldecode()](http://php.net/urldecode)?

Comment: Maybe? I am getting a random URL with a random amounts of the codes in the string. Would that work for that? It seems like in the documentation you have to be able to say how many params there are to decode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`urldecode()` solved all my problems. Thanks @marekful